# node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' line: 286

Tags: react-native, build

i am trying to build my app but i am getting error building it
errors are:

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Ali Yousafzai\Desktop\ProjectFiver\BluetoothPlanner\node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' line: 286
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

this is my react.gradle file

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) Meta Platforms, Inc. and affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
import org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm

def config = project.hasProperty("react") ? project.react : [:];

def detectEntryFile(config) {
    if (System.getenv('ENTRY_FILE')) {
        return System.getenv('ENTRY_FILE')
    } else if (config.entryFile) {
        return config.entryFile
    } else if ((new File("${projectDir}/../../index.android.js")).exists()) {
        return "index.android.js"
    }

    return "index.js";
}

def composeSourceMapsPath = config.composeSourceMapsPath ?: "node_modules/react-native/scripts/compose-source-maps.js"
def bundleAssetName = config.bundleAssetName ?: "index.android.bundle"
def entryFile = detectEntryFile(config)
def bundleCommand = config.bundleCommand ?: "bundle"
def reactRoot = file(config.root ?: "../../")
def inputExcludes = config.inputExcludes ?: ["android/**", "ios/**"]
def bundleConfig = config.bundleConfig ? "${reactRoot}/${config.bundleConfig}" : null ;
def enableVmCleanup = config.enableVmCleanup == null ? true : config.enableVmCleanup
def hermesCommand = config.hermesCommand

/**
 * Detects CLI location in a similar fashion to the React Native CLI
 */
def detectCliPath(config, reactRoot) {
    // 1. preconfigured path
    if (config.cliPath) {
        def cliJsAbsolute = new File(config.cliPath)
        if (cliJsAbsolute.exists()) {
            return cliJsAbsolute.getAbsolutePath()
        }
        def cliJsRelativeToRoot = new File("${rootDir}/${config.cliPath}")
        if (cliJsRelativeToRoot.exists()) {
            return cliJsRelativeToRoot.getAbsolutePath()
        }
        def cliJsRelativeToProject = new File("${projectDir}/${config.cliPath}")
        if (cliJsRelativeToProject.exists()) {
            return cliJsRelativeToProject.getAbsolutePath()
        }
    }

    // 2. node module path
    def cliJsFromNode = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/cli').bin"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
    if (cliJsFromNode.exists()) {
        return cliJsFromNode.getAbsolutePath()
    }

    // 3. cli.js in the root folder
    def rootCliJs = new File(reactRoot, "node_modules/react-native/cli.js")
    if (rootCliJs.exists()) {
        return rootCliJs.getAbsolutePath()
    }

    throw new Exception("Couldn't determine CLI location. " +
             "Please set `project.ext.react.cliPath` to the path of the react-native cli.js file. " +
             "This file typically resides in `node_modules/react-native/cli.js`");
}

def reactNativeDevServerPort() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDevServerPort")
    return value != null ? value : "8081"
}

def reactNativeInspectorProxyPort() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeInspectorProxyPort")
    return value != null ? value : reactNativeDevServerPort()
}

def getHermesOSBin() {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) return "win64-bin";
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_MAC)) return "osx-bin";
    if (Os.isOs(null, "linux", "amd64", null)) return "linux64-bin";
    throw new Exception("OS not recognized. Please set project.ext.react.hermesCommand " +
                        "to the path of a working Hermes compiler.");
}

// Make sure not to inspect the Hermes config unless we need it,
// to avoid breaking any JSC-only setups.
def getHermesCommand = {
    // 1. If the project specifies a Hermes command, don't second guess it.
    if (config.hermesCommand?.trim()) {
        if (hermesCommand.contains("%OS-BIN%")) {
            return hermesCommand
                .replaceAll("%OS-BIN%", getHermesOSBin())
                .replace('/' as char, File.separatorChar)
        } else {
            return hermesCommand
                .replace('/' as char, File.separatorChar)
        }
    }

    def hermescBin = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? 'hermesc.exe' : 'hermesc'

    // 2. If the project is building hermes-engine from source, use hermesc from there
    // Also note that user can override the hermes source location with
    // the `REACT_NATIVE_OVERRIDE_HERMES_DIR` env variable.
    def hermesOverrideDir = System.getenv("REACT_NATIVE_OVERRIDE_HERMES_DIR")
    def builtHermesc = hermesOverrideDir ?
        new File(hermesOverrideDir, "build/bin/$hermescBin") :
        new File(reactRoot, "node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine/build/hermes/bin/$hermescBin")

    if (builtHermesc.exists()) {
        return builtHermesc.getAbsolutePath()
    }

    // 3. If the react-native contains a pre-built hermesc, use it.
    def prebuiltHermesPath = "node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermesc/%OS-BIN%/$hermescBin"
        .replaceAll("%OS-BIN%", getHermesOSBin())
        .replace('/' as char, File.separatorChar);
    def prebuiltHermes = new File(reactRoot, prebuiltHermesPath)
    if (prebuiltHermes.exists()) {
        return prebuiltHermes.getAbsolutePath()
    }

    throw new Exception("Couldn't determine Hermesc location. " +
        "Please set `project.ext.react.hermesCommand` to the path of the hermesc binary file. " +
        "node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermesc/%OS-BIN%/hermesc");
}

// Set enableHermesForVariant to a function to configure per variant,
// or set `enableHermes` to True/False to set all of them
def enableHermesForVariant = config.enableHermesForVariant ?: {
    def variant -> config.enableHermes ?: false
}

// Set hermesFlagsForVariant to a function to configure per variant,
// or set `hermesFlagsRelease` and `hermesFlagsDebug` to an array
def hermesFlagsForVariant = config.hermesFlagsForVariant ?: {
    def variant ->
        def hermesFlags;
        if (variant.name.toLowerCase().contains("release")) {
            // Can't use ?: since that will also substitute valid empty lists
            hermesFlags = config.hermesFlagsRelease
            if (hermesFlags == null) hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
        } else {
            hermesFlags = config.hermesFlagsDebug
            if (hermesFlags == null) hermesFlags = []
        }
        return hermesFlags
}

// Set disableDevForVariant to a function to configure per variant,
// defaults to `devDisabledIn${targetName}` or True for Release variants and False for debug variants
def disableDevForVariant = config.disableDevForVariant ?: {
    def variant ->
      config."devDisabledIn${variant.name.capitalize()}" ||
      variant.name.toLowerCase().contains("release")
}

// Set bundleForVariant to a function to configure per variant,
// defaults to `bundleIn${targetName}` or True for Release variants and False for debug variants
def bundleForVariant = config.bundleForVariant ?: {
    def variant ->
      config."bundleIn${variant.name.capitalize()}" ||
      config."bundleIn${variant.buildType.name.capitalize()}" ||
      variant.name.toLowerCase().contains("release")
}

// Set deleteDebugFilesForVariant to a function to configure per variant,
// defaults to True for Release variants and False for debug variants
def deleteDebugFilesForVariant = config.deleteDebugFilesForVariant ?: {
    def variant -> variant.name.toLowerCase().contains("release")
}

android {
    buildTypes.all {
        resValue "integer", "react_native_dev_server_port", reactNativeDevServerPort()
        resValue "integer", "react_native_inspector_proxy_port", reactNativeInspectorProxyPort()
    }
}

def jvmVersion = Jvm.current().javaVersion.majorVersion
if (jvmVersion.toInteger() <= 8) {
    println "\n\n\n"
    println "**************************************************************************************************************"
    println "\n\n"
    println "ERROR: requires JDK11 or higher."
    println "Incompatible major version detected: '" + jvmVersion + "'"
    println "\n\n"
    println "**************************************************************************************************************"
    println "\n\n\n"
    System.exit(1)
}

afterEvaluate {
    def isAndroidLibrary = plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")
    def variants = isAndroidLibrary ? android.libraryVariants : android.applicationVariants
    variants.all { def variant ->
        // Create variant and target names
        def targetName = variant.name.capitalize()
        def targetPath = variant.dirName

        // React js bundle directories
        def jsBundleDir = file("$buildDir/generated/assets/react/${targetPath}")
        def resourcesDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/${targetPath}")

        def jsBundleFile = file("$jsBundleDir/$bundleAssetName")
        def jsSourceMapsDir = file("$buildDir/generated/sourcemaps/react/${targetPath}")
        def jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir = file("$buildDir/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/${targetPath}")
        def jsPackagerSourceMapFile = file("$jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir/${bundleAssetName}.packager.map")
        def jsCompilerSourceMapFile = file("$jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir/${bundleAssetName}.compiler.map")
        def jsOutputSourceMapFile = file("$jsSourceMapsDir/${bundleAssetName}.map")

        // Additional node and packager commandline arguments
        def nodeExecutableAndArgs = config.nodeExecutableAndArgs ?: ["node"]
        def cliPath = detectCliPath(config, reactRoot)

        def execCommand = []

        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            execCommand.addAll(["cmd", "/c", *nodeExecutableAndArgs, cliPath])
        } else {
            execCommand.addAll([*nodeExecutableAndArgs, cliPath])
        }

        def enableHermes = enableHermesForVariant(variant)

        def currentBundleTask = tasks.create(
            name: "bundle${targetName}JsAndAssets",
            type: Exec) {
            group = "react"
            description = "bundle JS and assets for ${targetName}."

            // Create dirs if they are not there (e.g. the "clean" task just ran)
            doFirst {
                jsBundleDir.deleteDir()
                jsBundleDir.mkdirs()
                resourcesDir.deleteDir()
                resourcesDir.mkdirs()
                jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir.deleteDir()
                jsIntermediateSourceMapsDir.mkdirs()
                jsSourceMapsDir.deleteDir()
                jsSourceMapsDir.mkdirs()
            }

            // Set up inputs and outputs so gradle can cache the result
            inputs.files fileTree(dir: reactRoot, excludes: inputExcludes)
            outputs.dir(jsBundleDir)
            outputs.dir(resourcesDir)

            // Set up the call to the react-native cli
            workingDir(reactRoot)

            // Set up dev mode
            def devEnabled = !disableDevForVariant(variant)

            def extraArgs = []

            if (bundleConfig) {
                extraArgs.add("--config")
                extraArgs.add(bundleConfig)
            }

            // Hermes doesn't require JS minification.
            if (enableHermes && !devEnabled) {
                extraArgs.add("--minify")
                extraArgs.add("false")
            }

            if (config.extraPackagerArgs) {
                extraArgs.addAll(config.extraPackagerArgs)
            }

            commandLine(*execCommand, bundleCommand, "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
                "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir,
                "--sourcemap-output", enableHermes ? jsPackagerSourceMapFile : jsOutputSourceMapFile, *extraArgs)


            if (enableHermes) {
                doLast {
                    def hermesFlags = hermesFlagsForVariant(variant)
                    def hbcTempFile = file("${jsBundleFile}.hbc")
                    exec {
                        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                            commandLine("cmd", "/c", getHermesCommand(), "-emit-binary", "-out", hbcTempFile, jsBundleFile, *hermesFlags)
                        } else {
                            commandLine(getHermesCommand(), "-emit-binary", "-out", hbcTempFile, jsBundleFile, *hermesFlags)
                        }
                    }
                    ant.move(
                        file: hbcTempFile,
                        toFile: jsBundleFile
                    );
                    if (hermesFlags.contains("-output-source-map")) {
                        ant.move(
                            // Hermes will generate a source map with this exact name
                            file: "${jsBundleFile}.hbc.map",
                            tofile: jsCompilerSourceMapFile
                        );
                        exec {
                            // TODO: set task dependencies for caching

                            // Set up the call to the compose-source-maps script
                            workingDir(reactRoot)
                            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                                commandLine("cmd", "/c", *nodeExecutableAndArgs, composeSourceMapsPath, jsPackagerSourceMapFile, jsCompilerSourceMapFile, "-o", jsOutputSourceMapFile)
                            } else {
                                commandLine(*nodeExecutableAndArgs, composeSourceMapsPath, jsPackagerSourceMapFile, jsCompilerSourceMapFile, "-o", jsOutputSourceMapFile)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            enabled bundleForVariant(variant)
        }

        // Expose a minimal interface on the application variant and the task itself:
        variant.ext.bundleJsAndAssets = currentBundleTask
        currentBundleTask.ext.generatedResFolders = files(resourcesDir).builtBy(currentBundleTask)
        currentBundleTask.ext.generatedAssetsFolders = files(jsBundleDir).builtBy(currentBundleTask)

        // registerGeneratedResFolders for Android plugin 3.x
        if (variant.respondsTo("registerGeneratedResFolders")) {
            variant.registerGeneratedResFolders(currentBundleTask.generatedResFolders)
        } else {
            variant.registerResGeneratingTask(currentBundleTask)
        }
        variant.mergeResourcesProvider.get().dependsOn(currentBundleTask)

        // packageApplication for Android plugin 3.x
        def packageTask = variant.hasProperty("packageApplication")
            ? variant.packageApplicationProvider.get()
            : tasks.findByName("package${targetName}")
        if (variant.hasProperty("packageLibrary")) {
            packageTask = variant.packageLibrary
        }

        // pre bundle build task for Android plugin 3.2+
        def buildPreBundleTask = tasks.findByName("build${targetName}PreBundle")

        def resourcesDirConfigValue = config."resourcesDir${targetName}"
        if (resourcesDirConfigValue) {
            def currentCopyResTask = tasks.create(
                name: "copy${targetName}BundledResources",
                type: Copy) {
                group = "react"
                description = "copy bundled resources into custom location for ${targetName}."

                from(resourcesDir)
                into(file(resourcesDirConfigValue))

                dependsOn(currentBundleTask)

                enabled(currentBundleTask.enabled)
            }

            packageTask.dependsOn(currentCopyResTask)
            if (buildPreBundleTask != null) {
                buildPreBundleTask.dependsOn(currentCopyResTask)
            }
        }

        def currentAssetsCopyTask = tasks.create(
            name: "copy${targetName}BundledJs",
            type: Copy) {
            group = "react"
            description = "copy bundled JS into ${targetName}."

            from(jsBundleDir)
            if (config."jsBundleDir${targetName}") {
                into(file(config."jsBundleDir${targetName}"))
            } else {
                into ("$buildDir/intermediates")
                if (isAndroidLibrary) {
                    into ("library_assets/${variant.name}/out")
                } else {
                    into ("assets/${targetPath}")

                    // Workaround for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2+ new asset directory
                    into ("merged_assets/${variant.name}/merge${targetName}Assets/out")

                    // Workaround for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4+ new asset directory
                    into ("merged_assets/${variant.name}/out")

                    // Workaround for Android Gradle Plugin 7.1 asset directory
                    into("$buildDir/intermediates/assets/${variant.name}/merge${targetName}Assets")
                }
            }

            // mergeAssets must run first, as it clears the intermediates directory
            dependsOn(variant.mergeAssetsProvider.get())

            enabled(currentBundleTask.enabled)
            dependsOn(currentBundleTask)
        }

        // mergeResources task runs before the bundle file is copied to the intermediate asset directory from Android plugin 4.1+.
        // This ensures to copy the bundle file before mergeResources task starts
        def mergeResourcesTask = tasks.findByName("merge${targetName}Resources")
        mergeResourcesTask.dependsOn(currentAssetsCopyTask)

        packageTask.dependsOn(currentAssetsCopyTask)
        if (buildPreBundleTask != null) {
            buildPreBundleTask.dependsOn(currentAssetsCopyTask)
        }

        // Delete the VM related libraries that this build doesn't need.
        // The application can manage this manually by setting 'enableVmCleanup: false'
        //
        // This should really be done by packaging all Hermes related libs into
        // two separate HermesDebug and HermesRelease AARs, but until then we'll
        // kludge it by deleting the .so files out of the /transforms/ directory.
        def cleanup = deleteDebugFilesForVariant(variant)

        def vmSelectionAction = { libDir ->
            fileTree(libDir).matching {
                if (enableHermes) {
                    // For Hermes, delete all the libjsc* files
                    include "**/libjsc*.so"

                    if (cleanup) {
                        // Reduce size by deleting the debugger/inspector
                        include '**/libhermes-executor-debug.so'
                    } else {
                        // Release libs take precedence and must be removed
                        // to allow debugging
                        include '**/libhermes-executor-release.so'
                    }
                } else {
                    // For JSC, delete all the libhermes* files
                    include "**/libhermes*.so"
                }
            }.visit { details ->
                def targetVariant1 = ".*/transforms/[^/]*/${variant.name}/.*"
                def targetVariant2 = ".*/merged_native_libs/${variant.name}/out/lib/.*"
                def targetVariant3 = ".*/stripped_native_libs/${variant.name}/out/lib/.*"
                def path = details.file.getAbsolutePath().replace(File.separatorChar, '/' as char)
                if ((path.matches(targetVariant1) || path.matches(targetVariant2) || path.matches(targetVariant3)) && details.file.isFile()) {
                    details.file.delete()
                }
            }
        }

        if (enableVmCleanup) {
            def task = tasks.findByName("package${targetName}")
            if (task != null) {
                def transformsLibDir = "$buildDir/intermediates/transforms/"
                task.doFirst { vmSelectionAction(transformsLibDir) }
            }

            def sTask = tasks.findByName("strip${targetName}DebugSymbols")
            if (sTask != null) {
                def strippedLibDir = "$buildDir/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/${variant.name}/out/lib/"
                sTask.doLast { vmSelectionAction(strippedLibDir) }
            }

            def mTask = tasks.findByName("merge${targetName}NativeLibs")
            if (mTask != null) {
                def mergedLibDir = "$buildDir/intermediates/merged_native_libs/${variant.name}/out/lib/"
                mTask.doLast { vmSelectionAction(mergedLibDir) }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Patch needed for https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210
// This is a patch to short-circuit the "+" dependencies inside the
// users' app/build.gradle file and the various .gradle files of libraries.
// As using plain "+" dependencies causes Gradle to always download the latest,
// this logic forces Gradle to use latest release in the minor series.
project.rootProject.allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.+"
            force "com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:0.70.+"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation, the problem is when you have a space in the directory path.

This only happens on Windows + Hermes + folders that have a space in the path

For more details check this [post](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34878)

A quick fix is ​​to remove the space from the path

C:\Users\Ali Yousafzai\ -> C:\Users\AliYousafzai\

**or**

Just zip your project and move the file to a folder with no space

C:\yourproject